# cannot apply hover property to complete class in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight the entire class element on hover. but I am unable to achieve it.here is what's happening.

on hover of a button, only a tag's background color is changing, but I have provided selector as "button" class.
what is going wrong here? 
how do I change the background color of button class (entire li item) on hover?

I am new to web development, good clarification will be appreciated.

```css
.button {
  height: fit-content;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ff0023;
}

.button :hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<li class="button">
  <a href="#aboutus">about us</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You must remove the space between .button and :hover. Like this .button:hover {

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There should be no SPACE between button and hover in css. Hope this will help you.

```css
.button {
height: fit-content;
width: 150px;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px;
text-align: center;
background-color: gray;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
float: left ;
border: 1px solid #ff0023;
 }

.button:hover {
     background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
 <li class="button">
    <a  href="#aboutus" >about us</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: thanks. it is working the way i expected. good learning for me.

Comment: but i am wondering how the a tag inside  button class is applied with :hover when there is space ?

Comment: @AyyappaGollu Sorry I am unable to get your question. Please make your question clear.

Comment: i was asking , the code i posted has SPACE between button and :hover right. in that case hover property should never work on any item right as syntax is wrong, but in my posted code the anchor tag(a tag)'s background-color inside button class (li item) is changing on hovered.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `.button:hover` not `.button: hover`

```css
.button {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ff0023;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<li class="button">
  <a href="#aboutus">about us</a>
</li>
```